# How do you switch route for different display size reactively?

Tags: vuejs2, routes

Is there a simple clean way to serve different routes for different displays updating the route when the size changes?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a `resize` listener and specify the needed breakpoints, then just push the needed route depending on the current breakpoint (window width):

### Codepen:

https://codepen.io/AlekseiHoffman/pen/NWPWZQx?editors=1010

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.windowResizeHandler)
  })
},
created() {
  this.windowResizeHandler(); // check size on load as well
},
beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.windowResizeHandler)
},
methods: {
  windowResizeHandler(event) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 650) {
      // change route here
      // this.$router.push('ROUTE_NAME').catch(err => {})         
    }
    else {
      // change route here
      // this.$router.push('ROUTE_NAME').catch(err => {})         
    }
  }
}
```